# How to ignore new lines in lodash orderBy

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I'm ordering an array using lodash/orderBy.  I have no control over what comes back in the array.  When my array items have new lines in them, then then they don't order as I expect them to.  Is there any way to ignore the new lines?  Or any other way to get the items to order correctly?

```
const shouldBeFirst = 'My message\r\n\r\nshould consist of A A A A some 
text';
const shouldBeSecond= 'My message\r\n\r\nshould consist of \r\n\r\n some 
text';

const array = [
 { text: 'xxx' },
 { text: shouldBeFirst },
 { text: 'yyy' },
 { text: shouldBeSecond},
 { text: 'zzz' }];

const ordered = orderBy(array, ['day'], ['asc']);
```

The order I expect to get these items in is

```
 { text: shouldBeFirst },
 { text: shouldBeSecond},
 { text: 'xxx' },
 { text: 'yyy' },
 { text: 'zzz' }];
```

However the order I get them in is:

```
 { text: shouldBeSecond },
 { text: shouldBeFirst },,
 { text: 'xxx' },
 { text: 'yyy' },
 { text: 'zzz' }];
```

[edit: in actual fact I need to sort by more fields, so the actual sort will look more like the code below]

```
 const array = [
 { text: 'xxx', day: 'monday', hour: '12' },
 { text: shouldBeFirst, day: 'tuesday', hour: '12' },
 { text: 'yyy', day: 'wednesday', hour: '12' },
 { text: shouldBeSecond, day: 'thursday', hour: '12'},
 { text: 'zzz', day: 'friday', hour: '12' }];

const ordered = orderBy(array, ['day', 'hour', 'text'], ['asc', 'asc', 'asc']);
```

Comment: Is this `orderBy(array, 'text')`?

Comment: What do you want, to ignore the new lines or have them bubbled to the top of the sort?

Comment: Ignore the new lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's indeed possible to use `orderBy`:

You can do that using [`orderBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#orderBy) by supplying a function for the comparison.

```js
const shouldBeFirst = 'My message\r\n\r\nshould consist of A A A A some text';
const shouldBeSecond= 'My message\r\n\r\nshould consist of \r\n\r\n some text';

const array = [
 { text: 'xxx' },
 { text: shouldBeFirst },
 { text: 'yyy' },
 { text: shouldBeSecond},
 { text: 'zzz' }];

const ordered = _.orderBy(array, item => item.text.replace(/\s+/g, " "));

console.log(ordered)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The replacement can be adjusted, if needed - this is just to illustrate how it can be defined. Multiple criteria can still be passed in as an array

```js
const shouldBeFirst = 'My message\r\n\r\nshould consist of A A A A some text';
const shouldBeSecond= 'My message\r\n\r\nshould consist of \r\n\r\n some text';

const array = [
 { text: 'xxx', value: 2 },
 { text: 'xxx', value: 1 },
 { text: shouldBeFirst },
 { text: 'yyy', value: 42 },
 { text: 'yyy', value: 12 },
 { text: shouldBeSecond},
 { text: 'zzz', value: 7 }];

//separating criteria for better readability
const criteria1 = item => item.text.replace(/\s+/g, " ");
const criteria2 = 'value'; //you can still pick by property name

//order by sanitized values of the text property first, followed by the value property
const ordered = _.orderBy(array, [criteria1, criteria2]);

console.log(ordered);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `_.sortBy` instead. You can map the values before ordering:

```
const ordered = _.sortBy(array, arrayItem => arrayItem.text.replace(/\W+/g, " "));
```

That `/\W+/g` is a regex that removes all non-alphanumeric characters from the array item before comparing it.

And, if you'd like to sort by multiple values:

```
const ordered = _(array).chain()
                        .sortBy(arrayItem => arrayItem.day)
                        .sortBy(arrayItem => arrayItem.hour)
                        .sortBy(arrayItem => arrayItem.text.replace(/\W+/g, " "))
                        .value();
```

But, this will sort weekday alphabetically instead of by order in the week - you can always use the `moment` library to get the index of the weekday and return that instead.

Comment: I want to sort on a number of different fields (I've amended the question to reflect this).  Will sortBy still work?

Comment: @rozza yes, check my modified answer

Comment: Multiple `.sortBy`s will *replace* the order every time. So if you want to sort by, say, `lastName` followed by `firstName` you'd get *different* results. A multi-criteria single sort will stably produce `Fred Bloggs -> Zoe Bloggs -> Alice Cooper`, while consecutive sorts will yield `Alice Cooper -> Fred Bloggs -> Zoe Bloggs` and even then, the last two could be swapped, depending on the sorting algorithm employed.

Comment: @vlaz Not exactly; it's a stable sort, meaning when two items are equal the sorter will leave them in the same order it found them. So, you have to start with the least important field and go towards more important. My example assumes the most important is the text property.

Comment: @André-JacquesdeBeer Apologies. I looked into it and it appears that lodash implements its own sorting. I was under the assumption that it delegated to [the default `.sort()` method, which is not necessarily stable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) - the specs do allow it to not be and, indeed, different implementations across engine might swap "equal" values around, so an input containing `Fred Bloggs -> Zoe Bloggs`, if sorted by last name, could end up with `Zoe Bloggs -> Fred Bloggs`.